# C++ Experimental filesystem has no "relative" function?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm stuck with GCC7.1 for which I have to use `#include <experimental/filesystem>` instead of `#include <filesystem>`.

So I have `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;` and then in the code I use `fs::relative(p, base)` which gives me `error: ‘relative’ is not a member of ‘fs’`.

It was working with normal C++17 filesystem, but doesn't seem to be present in experimental::filesystem. **How can I use relative function with experimental::filesystem?**

Comment: Why are you stuck with GCC7.1 ?

Comment: The question also could be: How do I use lambda in gcc.2.2.3? If your functionality is not part of the delivered implementation of a given version, you simply have to accept it or write your own or backport from newer version. BTW: It takes only some minutes to build a current gcc version from scratch. To stay with old tools and want actual features sounds a bit strange. Isn't it? And if you are bound to 7.x series, why not at minimum update to recent bug fix release of gcc 7.x series?

Comment: I'm stuck because it's a huge system/company and people who provide tools standarized to this version (for some reason) and I have no control over it. And the question is not like your lambda example - for example `path.is_regular_file()` didn't work in std::experimental, but I managed to do it with `fs::is_regular_file(path)` - so I though that maybe there's workaround for fs::relative.

Comment: "I'm stuck because it's a huge system/company and people who provide tools standarized to this version (for some reason)" Congratulations! There is something wrong within your company and with such people! If you KNOW you use an outdated compiler with already known bugs more than two and a half year older as the last bug fix release but you stay with that buggy thing, than it is quite hard to believe that you are working in a professional environment. There might be "some reasons" to stay on 7series but not on known buggy tools which have already updates.

Comment: For what it’s worth, the reason it’s missing is that it [was added](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0219r1.html) only at the same time as the whole TS was merged into C++17.

Comment: @Klaus And? What's your point? Sometimes it's just like that. You work for people who want you to use certain tools with certain outdated versions and you just can't do much about it except quitting the job. But guess what? There are people out here, who need those jobs in order to pay their rent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use third-party implementation (for ex. boost) or provide your own, something like (no complete solution - some extra edge cases need to be handled):

```
path relative(path p, path base)
{
    // 1. convert p and base to absolute paths
    p = fs::absolute(p);
    base = fs::absolute(base);

    // 2. find first mismatch and shared root path
    auto mismatched = std::mismatch(p.begin(), p.end(), base.begin(), base.end());

    // 3. if no mismatch return "."
    if (mismatched.first == p.end() && mismatched.second == base.end())
        return ".";

    auto it_p = mismatched.first;
    auto it_base = mismatched.second;

    path ret;

    // 4. iterate abase to the shared root and append "../"
    for (; it_base != base.end(); ++it_base)  ret /= ".."; 

    // 5. iterate from the shared root to the p and append its parts
    for (; it_p != p.end(); ++it_p) ret /= *it_p; 

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will use something like this. Does the trick. Just a note: you should probably add condition `if (!it_base->empty())` before `ret/=".."` - otherwise it will add unnecessary ".." for trailing "/".

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote - the edge cases need to be considered

Answer (score 1):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63900421/9323999, it would be better to call `weakly_canonical()` backport instead of `absolute()` to properly handle '.' and '..' in paths. And as the answer above "(no complete solution - some extra edge cases need to be handled)":

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] inline path weakly_canonical(path p)
{
    // 1. convert p to an absolute path
    p = absolute(p);

    // 2. declare special strings to handle
    using path_sv = std::basic_string_view<path::value_type>;
    static constexpr path_sv dot{"."};
    static constexpr path_sv dotdot{".."};

    // 3. iterate `p` to handle its parts
    path ret;
    for (const auto &part : p)
        if (part == dot)
            continue; // skip '.'
        else if (part == dotdot)
            ret = ret.parent_path(); // move to parent path on '..'
        else
            ret /= part; // add other entries to the result

    return ret;
}
```